# Error loading snazzy-info-window module in .Net Core 2.0 Angular 2 SPA Template

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to install the following plugin to my .Net Core SPA;

[Angular Google Maps Snazzy Window Link](https://angular-maps.com/guides/snazzy-info-window/custom-info-windows-with-snazzy-info-window/)

I have run the following steps;

added the following to my package.json;

```
"agm-core": "1.0.0-beta.5",
"agm-snazzy-info-window": "1.0.0-beta.5",
```

I have then right click inside Visual Studio and updated packages.

I then added the module to my app.shared.module.ts;

```
import { AgmCoreModule } from 'agm-core';
import { AgmSnazzyInfoWindowModule } from 'agm-snazzy-info-window';

AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
    apiKey: 'my-api-key'
}),
AgmSnazzyInfoWindowModule
```

I have also since added the following to my webpack.config.vendor.js;

```
const nonTreeShakableModules = [
    ...
    'agm-snazzy-info-window'
];
```

And my html code in my component is;

```
        <agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom">
            <agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
                <agm-snazzy-info-window [maxWidth]="200" [closeWhenOthersOpen]="false">
                    <ng-template>
                        My first Snazzy Info Window!
                    </ng-template>
                </agm-snazzy-info-window>
            </agm-marker>
        </agm-map>
```

However, when I run i get the following error;

> ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/agm-snazzy-info-window/directives/snazzy-info-window.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'snazzy-info-window' in
>   'C:\Users\matt\Source\Repos\MyProject\node_modules\agm-snazzy-info-window\directives'
>   @
>   ./node_modules/agm-snazzy-info-window/directives/snazzy-info-window.js
>   88:39-74  @ ./node_modules/agm-snazzy-info-window/index.js  @
>   ./ClientApp/app/app.shared.module.ts  @
>   ./ClientApp/app/app.browser.module.ts  @ ./ClientApp/boot.browser.ts 
>   @ multi event-source-polyfill
>   webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=__webpack_hmr&dynamicPublicPath=true
>   ./ClientApp/boot.browser.ts

Now if I remove the snazzy info window ans just display the Google Map it works fine? Any ideas what I am doing wrong here please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error most likely occurs since [`snazzy-info-window`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/snazzy-info-window) package is missing which represents  a dependency for [`agm-snazzy-info-window`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@agm/snazzy-info-window), it needs to be installed as well, for example:

```
"@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.2",
"@agm/snazzy-info-window": "1.0.0-beta.2",
"snazzy-info-window": "^1.1.0"
```

In addition some basic style that get shipped with the `snazzy-info-window` npm package needs to be included, for example:

```
const nonTreeShakableModules = [
    'snazzy-info-window',
    'snazzy-info-window/dist/snazzy-info-window.css'
];
```